# How to create an automatically updating Google spreadsheet with information from Steam?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

How would I create an automatically updating Google spreadsheet containing information about Recent Activity in Steam?

Table must look like here:
[image: Table example]

But the hours column must automatically updating current hours from here: 
[image: Recent Activity]

Steam acc: http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en).

In A2:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays", "//span[@class='actual_persona_name']")
```

In B2: either

```
=IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays", "//div[@class='recentgame_quicklinks']/h2")
```

which will return "108.9 hours past 2 weeks", or

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays", "//div[@class='recentgame_quicklinks']/h2"),"[^ ]* [^ ]*")
```

where [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) cuts the string down to "108.9 hours".

If you are going to do this for several account, you may want to have a column for Account Id, e.g., PerfectPlays. For example, if this column is C, the first parameter of `IMPORTXML` would be

```
"http://steamcommunity.com/id/"&C2
```

Comment: Thx u a lot. But can i ask why i have 2 errors? http://i.gyazo.com/9bbabac8bb1710102adf2276bececb6d.png http://i.gyazo.com/ff368c40c6d17eed511c6ec837e64f6b.png

Comment: @user95432 Try to use a semicolon (`;`) instead of a comma (`,`): `=IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays"; "//span[@class='actual_persona_name']")`

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra  Last question. How can I get to auto-update a this info to another sheet? For example this table with "Steam acc" and "Hours" on sheet with name "123" but i want some of this information (not all, only what i need) about hours on other sheet. What should I write in cell on other sheet?

Comment: @user95432 You can use the `QUERY` formula to do that. Add the following in sheet _123_: `=QUERY('Other Sheet Name'!A:G; "SELECT A, D, G")`

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra Understood thx u! Sry for disturbing u again, but its possible take information about recent activity not from here (http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays), but from here (http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays/games/?tab=recent) and only about "Dota 2" hrs last two weeks?

Comment: @user95432 Why don't you post that as a question and we'll have a look at it !!

Comment: @Jacob Jan Tuinstra ok ill!