# How to create an auto updating Google spreadsheet with information from Steam?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

How would I create an automatically updating Google spreadsheet containing information about Recently Played in Steam?

Table must look like here: 
[image]

A2 taking information about account name from here: http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays with this code: `=IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays", "//span[@class='actual_persona_name']")`

B2 must take information about recentle played from here:
http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays/games/?tab=recent
But only from Dota 2 game.
Can someone help with code for B2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more complicated from your [other question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78835/how-to-create-an-automatically-updating-google-spreadsheet-with-information-from) about ImportXML with XPath, because the table on the page with `?tab=recent` is dynamically formed by a script. The table does not exist in the page source which ImportXML accesses.

Inspecting the source, one can see the data embedded in a script:

```
<script language="javascript">
...  "name":"Dota 2","last_played":1433455140,"hours":"97.3", ....
```

So, to get it:

1. Get all scripts on the page with XPath `//script` (it's also possible to get only the 12th that we need with `(//script)[12]`, but then the import will break when they add or remove some other script).
2. Extract the number of hours with [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en). This took me two commands because the [regex library](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt) that Google Spreadsheets use is pretty limited; it does not support either lookaheads or lookbehinds.
3. Add any text to the number that you want.

In a single line, this is done by

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays/games/?tab=recent", "//script")),"Dota\s+2[^{]*\d*\.\d+"),"[0-9.]*$")&" hrs last two weeks"
```

For readability, here is the linebroken and indented version.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(
  REGEXEXTRACT(
    CONCATENATE(
     IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays/games/?tab=recent", "//script")
    ),
    "Dota\s+2[^{]*\d*\.\d+"
  ),
  "[0-9.]*$"
) & " hrs last two weeks"
```