# Extracting GICS codes from Fidelity website

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath, importhtml, importdata

This is the website:

https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/goto/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=aapl&type=o-NavBar

I'm trying to pull out the following two pieces of data into a Google Sheet:

- Sector (GICS®)
- Industry (GICS®)

That is, I want the following two to show up for the above:

- Information Technology
- Technology Hardware, Storage & Peripherals

I've tried the usual techniques including:

- importData
- importHTML
- importXML (this gave an error).

The XPath's I've derived via Google's Inspect Element tool are:

- `//*[@id="companyProfile"]/div[8]/span/a`
- `//*[@id="companyProfile"]/div[13]/span/a`

Nothing has worked so far. How can I extract this data into a Google Sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `IMPORTXML` ignores the nodes with no text content: for example, taking `//div[3]` from the document where the body consists of

```
<div>First</div> <div>Second</div> <div></div> <div>Fourth</div>
```

results in "Fourth". So, when you count the `<div>` elements, skip over those where there is no text. The elements you are looking for are returned with

```
=IMPORTXML( url , "//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[4]/span")
```

and

```
=IMPORTXML( url , "//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[5]/span")
```

For a more robust solution, I advise not relying on the numbering of elements at all. The following command returns both values you want with a single call, one under another:

```
=IMPORTXML( url , "//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[@class='sub-heading']/span")
```

You can apply `TRANSPOSE` to the result  to put them side by side, if preferable. Or, if some custom positioning is needed, get one at a time with

```
=IMPORTXML( url , "//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[@class='sub-heading'][1]/span")
```

and

```
=IMPORTXML( url , "//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[@class='sub-heading'][2]/span")
```

Note that one should use single quotes in  an XPath command, since it's a string surrounded by double quotes.

---

Using *Inspect Element tool* is not an inherently bad idea (it shows a nice tree view of the document), but there is an important caveat: this tool shows the document **after** any JavaScript runs on the page, while `IMPORTXML` gets the source as it is **before** any JavaScript processing. This matters when some elements get added by a script (example in my answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78864/79865)). To see exactly what `IMPORTXML` works with, use right-click -> "View Page Source" in Chrome, or its equivalent in other browsers.

Comment: Appreciate the answer. So, using the Chrome "Inspect Element" tool is apparently not a good idea. Can you recommend a good tutorial for XPath? I find it really confusing (as I do Regex).

Comment: I commented on Inspect Element. The best tutorial on XPath is apparently still at W3schools, unfortunately. This [guide to ImportXML](https://www.distilled.net/blog/distilled/guide-to-google-docs-importxml/) looks good. For regex the resources are far more plentiful, e.g., http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: A follow-up question: is there a tool such as "Inspect Element" which lets me right click on some element in the page source to select an XPath to the content (or otherwise see the tree structure of the page source)? Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use the regular Inspect Element -> Copy XPath  if you disable JavaScript (in Chrome's Content Settings) prior to loading the page. Indeed, ImportHTML is like a browser with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: I'm back with another question. I really want to find "the" shortcut technique to find XPath info. When you evaluated this page, what was the **process** you used to determine that the correct XPath was (for instance) not `//*[@id="companyProfile"]/div[8]/span` but `//div[@id='companyProfile']/div[4]/span` ... are there some tools you used to help with this?

Comment: My process was thinking "why doesn't this work?", trying other indices instead of 8, and comparing the results to the content of the document. This lead me to the conclusion that empty nodes are ignored. I believe this is called "debugging".