# How to modify REGEXEXTRACT to import total hours played on Steam

Tags: google-sheets, regexextract

My problem is similar as the one answered here: [How to create an auto updating Google spreadsheet with information from Steam?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78858/how-to-create-an-auto-updating-google-spreadsheet-with-information-from-steam)

Only I need to modify the REGEXEXTRACTs to find total hours played instead of hours played last 2 weeks for Counter-strike

As a example I will use my own profile here http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964409756/games/

from which the most relevant part of the script is

"name":"Counter-Strike: 
Global 
Offensive","last_played":1489175820,"hours":"15.5","hours_forever":"3,780","friendlyURL":"CSGO",

So I am trying to get hours_forever which is in this example is 3780.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"hours_forever"":""([\d,]+)"",")
```

the `\d` and `,` inside the `[]` brackets means it will only extract either a digit or a comma

[image]