# Goggle Sheets IMPORTXML/REGEXEXTRACT out of date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, importxml, regexextract

Alright, so I found my basic answer from these posts, 2-3 years ago.

[Extract data from Steam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78858/how-to-create-an-auto-updating-google-spreadsheet-with-information-from-steam)

[Import total hours on Steam](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104048/how-to-modify-regexextract-to-import-total-hours-played-on-steam)

Steam has updated its website since then, so I've messed around with it and attempted to make it work.. this is currently what I have, and what I'm getting.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198103825553/games/", "//script")),"\(([Garry's Mod]+)\)"),"[0-9]+")&" hrs last two weeks"
```

> Error Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "[0-9]+" does not match
>   text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "o".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
 "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198103825553/games/", "//*"), 1, 2),
 "hours"":""", "♦"), "♦"), 1, 2), "\d+.\d+|\d+")&" hrs last two weeks"
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Much appreciated, this helps me learn as well, I didn't think of separating it bit by bit by using INDEX.

Comment: One thing I don't understand, however, is the usage of ♦
What exactly is it representing?

Comment: thats because of SPLIT coz if we would split by `hours":"` it would split stuff after each character eg. `h`, `o`, `u`, etc. so we convert `hours":"` to `♦` and split by unique symbol `"♦"`

Comment: Thank you so very much for the explanation! If you wouldn't mind, one more time. I attempted to edit the formula for another webpage, but I'm getting the error that valid INDEX values are only 1 and 0.
I'm assuming because the format of this website is different, there is a space between the word steamID64 and the digits I want to grab, as well as no quotes, but I'm not entirely sure.

    `=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTXML(
    "https://steamid.io/lookup/STEAM_0:0:194919430", "//*"), 1, 2),
    "SteamID64", "♦"), "♦"), 1, 2), "\d+")`

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://steamid.io/lookup/STEAM_0:0:194919430"),200,1),127,1),"\>(\d+)\<")`

Comment: Right before you posted that, I scrolled farther down in my sheets, and noticed everything was being put waaay down there. haha. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hey again! Sorry I keep bringing this up, you've been the best!!
I noticed when I plug in a different profile into the link, it only grab the game information (hours) that's on top.
`Example: https://steamid.io/lookup/76561198021550319`
So I attempted both of your answers, as well as a mix of the two, because I noticed when there are multiple game options, it can't seem to INDEX cell locations that may change at any time.
I attempted to add in =FILTER with the criteria being 'Garry', but no luck.
What else can I use?

Comment: well, there are no hours - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Melxt.png

Comment: My bad, that was the wrong link. Here is the correct one.
`https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198021550319`

Comment: `=QUERY({
 IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198021550319","//div[@class='game_name']"),
 IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198021550319","//div[@class='game_info_details']")},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col4")`

Comment: `=QUERY({
 IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198021550319","//div[@class='game_name']"),
 IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198021550319","//div[@class='game_info_details']")},
 "select Col1,Col2 where Col1 contains 'Garry'")`

Comment: Ah, so that's how you get specific xpath's, I've been trying to do this, and each time it says Empty Content, thank you so much!