# Import the whole table from nextgenstats.nfl.com

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, yahoo-fantasy-sports

I am trying to import the whole table from [this site](https://nextgenstats.nfl.com/stats/rushing) into a Google Sheet, but I keep getting the `imported content empty` error.

I realize this error is very common and I have done my fair share of research on this site before posting. Here's what I've tried so far:

1. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97588
   This answer addressed the same topic as my question but did not focus on how to grab the whole table, only a specific element from within that table.
2. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97615
   I also tried to go here, understanding that the solution probably has something to do with the source code maybe not including the proper  tags in the HTML. I tried the suggested solution and played around with it for a solid hour but to no avail.
3. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78864
   Finally, I tried this post thinking that the solution may have something to do with the fact that the site might update dynamically. So I also played around with the solution in that post, but alas to no avail.

Please be gentle with your responses, I am new here. But I am always willing to pick myself up and keep trying.

Comment: Welcome. Great work doing your “homework” but the question is too broad for this site. I suggest to focus it on using IMPORTXML or using Google Apps Script, maybe posting a question for each one but not to ask about both on the same question.

Comment: Thank you Ruben, will do!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `importxml` in this scenario because this website is built with Vue.js

> Vue.js is a JavaScript front end framework

Your best shot is to `Right clic` > `Inspect Element`
Then `Right clic` on the `table` element > `Edit as HTML`.

Now just `Copy` > `Paste` and exploit the data.

Comment: The related limitation isn't limited to `Vue.js`, it applies to any case where the data is added dynamically.