# How do I get my last played on a steam game from my profile

Tags: google-sheets

I am attempting to grab my last played on my steam games. I am currently working with this..

> =REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML("http://steamcommunity.com/id/PerfectPlays/games/?tab=recent", "//script")),"Dota\s+2[^{]*\d*.\d+"),"[0-9.]*$")&" hrs last two weeks"

I am trying to convert it so it will display the last time I played Dota 2. (Date Formatted)

I have been playing around with different things but I can't seem to figure out how this specifically figures out the hours played within the last 2 weeks.

Comment: Related [How to create an automatically updating Google spreadsheet with information from Steam?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78839/88163)

Comment: If you are still interested on this please briefly descript the relevant part of the source code of the webpage as well a sample value returned by IMPORTXML